# How do I create random in Eclipse?

Tags: image, file, random, filenames

I have 10 images and I want them to be prompt out randomly. What code should I use? I'm still an amateur so I hope I could get some answers here... The images are named like 'pic1', 'pic2' and so on. is it possible to get the number from the file name and use Math.random() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the pics in an Array.
Say array index is from 0 to 9
Use Java Math.random to get random number.
You need to multiply its result by 10 get indexes in your range

Comment: Is it possible to get a string to be grouped withe the picture?

Comment: Yes. You can create a class to hold String and picture and store the references of this class in Array